# Get values from two data ranges and use this in a join?

Tags: sql, join, between

```
SELECT sh.Nr_V, 
       tt.journalnumber, 
       sh.journalnumber_end, 
       sh.journalnumerstart 
 FROM transactiontable tt 
      LEFT JOIN salesheader sh
                ON tt.journalnumer between sh.journalnumerstart 
                   AND sh.journalnumber_end;
```

The above shows my idea about getting all `Nr_V` joined on my `transactiontable`.
So I want all values between `journalnumberstart` and `journalnumber_end` and the use them to join my `transactiontable`. This is not possible I cant get a join to work! The idea is to see `Nr_V` from `salesheader` joined on to my `transactiontable` - the problem is to look up the `journalnumber` in a range between two columns.

**SalesHeader**

```
Nr_V    JournalnumberStart JournalNumberEnd 

100       1001002             1003000
101       1003001             1004000
```

**SalesTransaktion**

```
Journalnumber  

1001004  
1001005
1003032
```

**OutPutTable**

```
Nr_V    JournalNumber 

100     1001004 
100     1001005
101     1003032
```

So what we want is to look up in the range of SalesHeader in order to get a relation between SalesTransaction and SalesHeader!
Please remember that I have 6 million rows in my transactiontable! and 50000 rows in my salesheader table.

Comment: Can you provide the skeleton schema of the tables

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would work:

```
SELECT sh.Nr_V, 
       tt.JournalNumber
FROM SalesTransaction tt 
LEFT JOIN SalesHeader sh ON 
  (tt.Journalnumber > sh.JournalnumberStart) 
  AND 
  (tt.Journalnumber < sh.JournalNumberEnd)
ORDER BY sh.Nr_V, tt.JournalNumber
```

Sample [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1c329/1)

Comment: Sorry it only gives me nulls!

Comment: @user3310846 Really? It gives the desired results when I run it with your example data. What DBMS are you using? I tried with MS SQL 2012.

Comment: I am using MS SQL 2012 enterprise. I am still getting nulls.

Comment: @user3310846 I don't know why it isn't working for you, the sample fiddle I provided suggest it should work :\

Comment: Hi my data is confidential so I just tried with the above into #temp tables that also works for me - I have tried to change the datatypes and trim the coloumns...that doesnt work still. I have to dig into it...Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT sh.nr_v, 
       st.journalnumber 
FROM   salesheader sh 
       LEFT JOIN salestransaction st 
              ON st.journalnumber BETWEEN sh.journalnumberstart AND 
                                          sh.journalnumberend;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1cf65/1)

Comment: Fiddle thats the example I tried(see top) that isnt working. That was my original query.

Comment: I tried it in MS SQL 2012 and its working [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1cf65/1)

Comment: Hi all the sql statement works now! The reason was blank spaces in some of the rows and some unicode mess. The problem was to see this in all 6 mill rows. But thanks for you help and support:-)

Comment: no prob...:) u could upvote the answer or accept it..;)